# PHP PDO SELECT statment returning nothing

Tags: php, sql, select, pdo

i don't know what i'm doing wrong here but i am simply trying to connect to a database search for a primary key and place the row inside an array. the best i can get is a blank screen which i was glad just to get that.help is very much appreciated.

```
 <?php

    include ('DatabaseAccessV2.php');

    $selectedData=new DatabaseAccess();
    $selectedData->tableToArray();

    ?> 

    <?php
 class DatabaseAccess{
    function tableToArray(){
            $dbName='db1';
            $table='table1';
            $i=1;
            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname='.$dbName, 'root', '');
            $sql = "select Close from '$table' where entryNum ='$i'";
            $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
            $sth->execute();
            $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            echo($result);
        }
}
```

Comment: No Error message and obvious wrong sql mistake.

Comment: Add `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Comment: Try this: `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname='.$dbName, 'root', '');` Also do: `printr_($result);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

*Firstly*, you're enclosing your table in single quotes which isn't the correct [**identifier**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html).

```
select Close from '$table'
```

where it should either be in ticks

```
select Close from `$table`
```

or remove them if you're not passing a potential reserved word or contains a hyphen or space in the table name, or anything to give MySQL to complain about.

```
select Close from $table
```

Add `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, which would have caught that error.

---

Then as Rizier123 stated in a comment, and quoting it:

> Try this: $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname='.$dbName, 'root', ''); Also do: printr_($result);

The way you have your port setup and should do as Rizier mentioned.

- That colon `:` should be an `=` sign.

#### Kudos to Rizier123

---

As per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

> More complete examples:

```
mysql:host=localhost;port=3307;dbname=testdb
mysql:unix_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock;dbname=testdb
```

and from http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=xxx;port=xxx;dbname=xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 
array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false));
```

Comment: Definitely a problem, but Rizier123 also brings up a good point about the port in the PDO constructor

Comment: @ChrisForrence Yes, that could also be an issue and that did cross my mind earlier. I will quote his comment, thank you Chris.